# setting 0 to 10 loop using ffmpeg filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to set filter looping (0 ≤ s ≤ 10), but using mod(t\,10) is (0 ≤ s < 10).

Using this filter now.

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i testsrc2=r=100,hue=s=print(mod(t\,10))
```

I want this.

```
0.00
0.01
:
:
10.00
0.01
:
looping
```

but mod(t,10) is

```
0.00
0.01
:
:
9.99
0.00
:
looping
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
print(mod(t\,10)+10*not(mod(t\,10))*gt(t\,0))
```

This will print 10 only if there is a frame whose timestamp is an exact multiple of 10.